# Negative Values of Scientific Notation in TXT file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a TXT file with a mixed floating numbers as a string represented lists. When I convert each element as a list of float numbers, negative scientific values do not appear in the new list. For example, when I have the following values:

```
line1 : [119.       114.        67.       117.706474 113.051278  69.933043]
line2 : [ 1.20000000e+02  0.00000000e+00  6.70000000e+01  1.20217686e+02
line3 : -8.89000000e-04  7.03216110e+01]
```

my output is

```
line1 : [119.       114.        67.       117.706474 113.051278  69.933043]
line2 : [ 1.20000000e+02  0.00000000e+00  6.70000000e+01  1.20217686e+02]
```

As you see the output does not show the numbers starting from negative value. How can I deal with this problem?

```
input_file = open('file.txt', 'r')
output_file = "new_file.txt"
lines = input_file.readlines()
#print(lines)


with open(output_file, "w") as filehandle:
  for line in lines:
      
      transformed_points = line.split('\n')
      a = transformed_points[0]
      #print(transformed_points[0].strip().replace('. ',','))
      a = a.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
      floats = [float(x) for x in a.split()]
      filehandle.write(str(floats[3:5])+' \n')
```

Comment: I just edited to fix the formatting, but I'm concerned the input is not properly formatted. If you need to fix it, you can [edit] it yourself of course.

Comment: My advice is to try to get a library function to read the file. Can you use pandas? There can be a lot of tricky edge cases, so it helps a lot if you can make use of what others have figured out.

Comment: Trying to reproduce the issue, the output I'm getting is totally different, like the first line is `[117.706474, 113.051278]`. You need to make a [mre]. Also, remove all the unused variables like `InputPoint_x`.

Comment: BTW, to remove the trailing newline more easily: `a = line.rstrip('\n')`

Comment: @RobertDodier I think using libraries makes the problem more complicated. I tried with pandas, but, then there were more issues popping up.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the follow-up! The input has two string type of lists. The second one is splitted into two rows as a result of a software output file. Since the second list has two rows, the output is also splitted from original line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can manually read this.
Not the cleanest implementation but it works.
You can just use this as a function to process the raw data lines.

```py
input_file = open('file.txt', 'r')
output = 'new_file.txt'
lines = input_file.read() 
# print(lines)

add = False
newlines=[]
for char in lines:
    if char == '[':
        add=True
        line = []
        continue
    if char ==']':
        add=False
        newlines.append(''.join(line))
        continue

    if char == '\n': continue
    if add == True: line.append(char)

newlines_float = [list(map(float,line.split())) for line in newlines]

for i in newlines_float:
   print(i)

input_file.close()

# the output of this is a nested list with float numbers.
# You can use f-string formatting to properly output this as you wish.
```

This outputs

```
[119.0, 114.0, 67.0, 117.706474, 113.051278, 69.933043]
[120.0, 0.0, 67.0, 120.217686, -0.000889, 70.321611]
```

Comment: `line[1:-1]` will remove the `2` from line 2

Comment: previous answer was made based on pre-edited input file. Its just a misinterpretation. This one should work now.

Comment: You are an awesome person! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

i think the input_files's example string is consist of 3 lines

```
line1 : '[119.       114.        67.       117.706474 113.051278  69.933043]'
line2 : '[ 1.20000000e+02  0.00000000e+00  6.70000000e+01  1.20217686e+02'
line3 : '-8.89000000e-04  7.03216110e+01]'
```

so if you use

```
for line in lines:
```

the example line3 is splited from original line(line2)
please check this

Comment: This explains me why I am getting weird outputs. I tried to fix one line and the outputs is as expected, worked like a charm! However, how can I implement in my code that lines should be in single row instead of splitting into two rows?

Comment: there are various way to implement the code. In my case, 
1. use <line.strip() > to delete the '\n' 
2. attach the whole lines to make long one sentence without '\n'
3. so we have '[blabla][blabla][blabla]'
4. now we can use split(']') and delete '[' properly like in your original code
5. and do rest thing, string -> float

Comment: Would you mind posting the code? I tried implementing, but no success.